# Wordpress Loads but query gives error message

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress to query the database and it worked fine for a long time. All of a sudden I'm getting error messages and it can't connect. I have some simple code like the following:

```
<?php
$qry = "Select * from dj_feedback_summary";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
?>
```

I get the following results:

> Warning: mysql_query(): No such file or directory in
>   /home/name/website.com/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42)
>   : eval()’d code on line 3
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in
>   /home/name/website.com/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42)
>   : eval()’d code on line 3

I don't understand why this is happening if I already have a connection that works with the database in my `wp-config.php` file.

If I make the code say the following:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

The output is correct so I know it isn't a plugin issue to display the PHP.

I'm using Wordpress 4.4 if it matters.

EDIT: It works if I just execute a query like in the suggested answer but why won't it work anymore with the regular `mysql` query?

Comment: did you switch web server?

Comment: Did you have some update on the side of your provider? The `mysql_` functions are rather old and your error says that the path to the mysql.sock file is wrong.

Comment: @Jan No, I've been on the same server and it's being hosted so I'm not sure if something was updated on their side.

Comment: this plugin was last updated 7 years ago :) checking the code now

Comment: @user1048676 If this is not your server there's not really much you can do except for contacting your provider.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress defines a class called wpdb, which contains a set of functions used to interact with a database.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

You can use wpdb for your db query.